# Using crash reporting in an open source application

Tags: c#

I would like to use crash reporting in an open source application. The code will be published and would include the implementation of the crash reporter API. In particular, the code displays the crash report account number in plain text. I am concerned that someone can take the account info from the code and troll/flood/pollute the crash report account.

Your thoughts? Maybe I can put the crash report account info in a dll so at least it is not publicly displayed in the source code.

I checked github and it seems very rare that an open source app will use a crash reporter service.

Comment: Designing proper security model and DOS prevention for your crash reporting site is way outside of scope of SO... I'd strongly recommend to use Fiddler to observe HTTP traffic to educate yourself on what information is directly available to a user of an application that sends data to a site before even attempting to implement security feature like you try to design.

Comment: I used Rollbar for Jexus Manager and other open source projects, and nobody would really flood your account unless there is surely something they can gain from that (money for example). If you do have a concern, you would have to omit the crash report account number from your code base, and only include it in your executable (a little on the edge of pure open source), but your users should appreciate that, as crash reports do help improve the product quality a lot.